# Prove a function has exactly one real root on interval $(0,\infty)$

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives, exponential-function, roots

I have a function

$$ f(x)=\left(1-e^{\lambda  x}\right) \left(1+e^x \left(u-1-e^{-u x}
   u\right)-x\right)+\lambda  \left(e^{\lambda  x} (1-u)+u\right)
   \left(x+e^x \left(e^{-u x}-1+(u-1) x\right)\right) $$
where $\lambda > 0$, and $0<u<1$ are parameters, and $f(x)$ is defined on $[0,\infty)$.

Below is how the function looks like when I plot on the interval (0,3) with $\lambda = 0.5$ and $u=0.5$.

[image: Plot of $f(x)$, with $\lambda = 0.5$ and $u=0.5$]

How to prove that $f(x)$ has *exactly* one real root on the interval $(0,\infty)$? The difficulty here is that $\lambda$ and $u$ are unknown parameters. I have no clue how to proceed. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It looks like there a point $p$ where $f'(x) > 0$ for $0 \le x < p$ and $f'(x) < 0$ for $x > p$. Unfortunately, it seems that you will have to get $f'(x)$.

Comment: Thanks @martycohen. For now, I can only establish the existence of the real roots due to the following. $f(0) = 0$, $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0+} f'(x) = 0$, and $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0+} f''(x) = \lambda (2 - u^2) > 0$ as $\lambda > 0$ and $0<u<1$. Thus, $f(x)$ is a strictly increasing function on the interval $(0,\epsilon)$, where $\epsilon$ is an arbitrarily small positive real number. We also have $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} f(x) = - \infty$. So $f(x)$ crosses the horizontal axis at least once. Hence, there exist at least one real root. But how to prove the uniqueness of the real root?